# Angular JS : angular.module[] across all files

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 files on my project. app.js, routes.js and controllers.js. I want to add LocalStorageModule to my project, so i tried in app.js

```
angular.app('myApp', ['LocalStorageModule']).config(function(localStorageServiceProvide) {
    // have some lines
});
```

In controllers.js

```
angular.module('myApp').
controller('TestCtrl', function(localStorageService) {
    // some line of codes
});
```

when i try to run the app,

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=localStorageServiceProvider%20%3C-%20localStorageService%20%3C-%20LoginController
at Error (native)
```

It says, Unknown provider, i am sure, this is not a LocaStorage Package problem, since i had tried with ngCookies to inject with app and got the same error. So i did not understand how the angular.module works across many files.

I googled and got some suggestions, angular.module('myApp') is the getter, then why it would not take the angular.module('myApp', ['appDependencies']) from app.js to other JS files, if i try to access localStorageService in app.js, it works. I assured, i am doing something wrong, can anyone suggest me, how to resolve this?

Comment: Show us your REAL code. The error doesn't match with the provided code. And there is now way a provider is named "localStorageServiceProvide". Also show us your html file.

Comment: Lil more code please. I see some issues but can't answer till i see more.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete, therefore impossible to test. A few errors I spot from what you have provided:

- You have misspelled the provider passed to config. The correct spelling is: *localStorageServiceProvide**r***.
- `angular.app` in your first line of code is probably wrong as it is not part of the core. I sense you meant to write `angular.module`.

The following code works:

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <section ng-controller="TestCtrl">{{test}}</section>
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.provider('localStorageService', function () {
    this.$get = function () {
        return true;
    }
})

.config(function (localStorageServiceProvider) {
    // have some lines
})

.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, localStorageService) {
    // some line of codes
    $scope.test = localStorageService;
});
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a5x4chve/)